# Why Collection assignment act differently inside method and consecutive lines?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> From the below results, I like to know why 'Test 2' have value as 30 ,
>   I expect the same result as in 'Test 3' (100) ?

Here is the fiddler link https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rco1mD for better understanding.

```
IList<Test> initialCollection = new List<Test>();
initialCollection.Add(new Test(){ Value = 30});

Console.WriteLine("Test 1 : Before update method : " + initialCollection.Last().Value );

UpdateValueCollection(initialCollection);

Console.WriteLine("Test 2: After update method : " + initialCollection.Last().Value );
IList<Test> check = new List<Test>();
check.Add(new Test(){ Value = 100});
initialCollection = check;

Console.WriteLine("Test 3: Same update method code added as consecutive line : " + initialCollection.Last().Value );
```

and my another method is

```
public void UpdateValueCollection(IList<Test> lstTest)
{
   IList<Test> check = new List<Test>();
   check.Add(new Test(){ Value = 100});
   lstTest = check;
}
```

The results are

```
Test 1 : Before update method : 30
Test 2 : After update method : 30
Test 3 : Same update method code added as consecutive line : 100
```

Comment: Because C# is pass by copy (unless you use `ref` or `out`.)  When you pass a reference type, a copy of that reference is made.  You can mutate what it refers to, but assigning a new value will not be visible to the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the second test you pass a copy of the value in `initialCollection` to `UpdateValueCollection`, in that method you disregard the value that was passed, create a new list, and then modify that list.  This method will never have any observable effects on any caller of this method.

Before test 3 you create a new list, give it a value, and then assign it to `initialCollection`, *mutating the value of that variable*.  Since you have changed the value of this variable, unlike your second test, it has caused an observable effect when you later get the value of that variable.

Had the method `UpdateValueCollection` passed the parameter *by reference* (through the use of the `ref` or `out` keywords) instead of *by value*, then the changes to the parameter would have also affected `initialCollection`, but as it was passed by value, only the copy of the variable was mutated.

Note that if you really wished `UpdateValueCollection` to compute a new list for your variable the more idiomatic design would be to have `UpdateValueCollection` *return a new list* instead of being `void`, and then to assign the value of that method to `initialCollection`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `lstTest = check;` within `UpdateValueCollection` you are only updating the reference `lstTest` visible within that method, you will need to pass `lstTest` by reference to be able to replace the list itself and have that visible outside the `UpdateValueCollection` method:

```
public void UpdateValueCollection(ref IList<Test> lstTest)
{
   IList<Test> check = new List<Test>();
   check.Add(new Test(){ Value = 100});
   lstTest = check;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those "strange" things probably happen because you give your method a reference to an IList. If you change now the value of your IList, you will update the reference only in this method.
That means that you play now in some other part of your RAM.

To solve this you have to change your reference to the reference of an IList.
Like this

```
public void UpdateValueCollection(ref IList<Test> lstTest)
{
   IList<Test> check = new List<Test>();
   check.Add(new Test(){ Value = 100});
   lstTest = check;
}
```